# DoCapture Api for Capture Pending payement

Tags: paypal

I developed a merchant website that use the **DoCapture** Api for Capture Pending payment.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/

It works !

Now my problem is how to delete Pending payement using API Call.
I Found   **DoVoid**  .

Is it the right command?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DoVoid would void a pending authorization.